# How to create infinitive random platform in endless running game?

Tags: libgdx

I'm making a 2d endless running game. I have a platform that is formed by many blocks. Every block has one of three color: red, blue, green. I don't know exactly how to random blocks with different color at runtime. I have used an array to store block rectangles like the example Drop(Simple game) on wiki page. In render class I have this code to change color of block at runtime:

```
public void drawBlock() {
  TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion();

  for (Rectangle rec : colorBlock.getBlocksRec()) {
     if (colorBlock.isRed()) {
        region = red;
     }
     if (colorBlock.isGreen())
        region = green;
     if (colorBlock.isBlue())
        region = blue;
     batch.draw(region, rec.x, rec.y, rec.width, rec.height);
  }
```

}

But it seems to be failed because it changes all blocks on screen into one color at the same time.

I also have some problems in making blocks move continuously. They moved but they looked like hundred of blocks overlapped each other. I don't know how to control the blocks in the right way. I used TimeUtils for check when the next block should be created, but it was totally failed.

Comment: No, i have just used rectangle overlap for collision and Vector2 for moving objects. In addition, I dont use Tiled map because I want to make endless running without levels. Thank you for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Array or your ground blocks that adds a new one when it about to appear on the screen, and removes the oldest entry when it will not be seen on the screen anymore. I had a similar question, check it out: [**HERE**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82087/2d-libgdx-runtime-level-generation)

For random colors you can use the MathUtils.random(float f) when you about to add a new block to the array.

For example something like this, or with switch :

```
float res = MathUtils.random(8f); 
//this returns a random float between 0 (inclusive) and 8 (exclusive)

if(res <= 2) { //[0-2]
//add green
}
if(res > 2 && res <= 5){//(2-5]
//add blue
}
if(res>5){//(5-8)
//add red
}
```